# A doubt regarding the proof of Theorem 24.1 in Munkres' "Topology".

Tags: general-topology

On pg. 249 of Munkres' "Topology", Theorem 24.1 says that if $L$ is a linear continuum in the order topology, then $L$ is connected.

He then proves this for every **convex** subspace of $L$.

I don't understand how the whole of $L$ can be connected, if we have only proved that convex subsets of $L$ are connected. Can we prove that every linear continuum ($L$ in this case) can be expressed as the union of non-disjoint convex subsets?

Thank you.

Comment: $L$ is a convex subset/subspace of itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linear continuum is convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/839550/linear-continuum-is-convex)

Answer (score 1):

$L$ is a convex subset of itself, trivially. Munkres thus proves a more general fact.