# Prove that a linear continuum L is a convex subset of itself.

Tags: general-topology

Prove that a linear continuum L is a convex subset of itself.

Everywhere it is stated that the result is trivially true.
I would like an explicit proof.

My trial:

Attempt 1. Does the fact that a linear continuum is densely ordered imply convex? That for every $a,b$ such that $a < b$, $[a,b]$ belongs to the linear continuum.

Attempt 2. Or are all sets convex sets of itself?

**Definitions.**

A simply ordered set L having more than one element is called a linear continuum if the following hold:

(1) $L$ has the least upper bound property

(2) If $x<y$, there exists z such that x

A subspace $Y$ of $L$ is said to be convex if for every pair of points $a,b$ of $Y$ with $a<b$, the entire interval $[a,b]$ of points of $L$ lies in $Y$.

Comment: By $[a, b]$, we mean all elements $z$ in $L$ such that $a \le z \le b$. So all sets are convex subsets of itself (this is trival in the sense that there is nothing to prove.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linear continuum is convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/839550/linear-continuum-is-convex)

Answer (score 1):

By [a,b], we mean all elements z in L such that a≤z≤b. So all sets are convex subsets of itself (this is trival in the sense that there is nothing to prove).

[Posting the answer from comments by Fermé somme]