# Why does the author assumes convexity of a subspace while proving the connectivity of a linear continuum?

Tags: general-topology

In the book of *Topology* by Munkres, at page 153, it is given that

> If $L$ is a linear continuum in the order topology, then $L$ is
>   connected and so are intervals and rays in $L$.

And in the proof,

> We prove that if $Y$ is a convex subspace of $L$, then $Y$ is
>   connected.

And indeed the author uses the convexity of $Y$ in the proof.However, in the theorem there is no mention of convexity, so I do not understand why does the author assume the convexity of a subspace of a linear continuum while proving the connectivity of that linear continuum ?

Comment: I don't have that book, but it seems to me that "every convex subspace of $L$ is connected" is just a more concise way of saying "$L$ is connected and so are intervals and rays in $L$" which is what he wants to prove, since that's what the theorem says. So I don't understand what's bothering you. What am I missing?

Comment: @bof Is the fact that $L$ is linear continuum implies  it is and its intervals  convex ?

Comment: @bof Made some research, and ashamed that I couldn't see $L$, its intervals and rays are convex :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intervals and rays are order-convex, clearly. The whole space is trivially so.

In a connected ordered space, the opposite is also true: all order convex subsets of $X$ are either $X$, an (open or closed) ray, or an (open, closed, half-open) interval.

Answer (score 1):

You say 'in the theorem there is no mention of convexity'.

But a statement about continuum, intervalls and rays in it is more or less exactly that: a Statement about convex objects.

And he is not assuming convexity, but using their common property as tool for the proof.

It is obvious that $L$ is convex, and it's discussed here: [Linear continuum is convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/839550/linear-continuum-is-convex)